# Ionic2 conditionally show span

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an accordion list in my ionic2 application. My component has JSON array of object as following:

```
this.days= [

        { "id": 0,
        "name": 'Ihr heutiger Trainingsplan',
        "exercises":[

        {"id":1,"name":'Best Stretch', "watchedToday": 'true', "type":"body"},
        {"id":8,"name":'Farben', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        {"id":2,"name":'Butterfly reverse', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":9,"name":'Punktgenaue Reaktion', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        {"id":3,"name":'SquatRow', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":10,"name":'Loslassen', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        // {"id":13,"name":'Wortpaare 1', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},
        {"id":4,"name":'Plank', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":11,"name":'Wortpaare', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}, //word-pair 1 : just show words

        {"id":5,"name":'Push Up', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"},
        {"id":12,"name":'Wortschatz', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"},

        // {"id":14,"name":'Wortschatz 1', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}, // word-pair 2 : actual game
        {"id":6,"name":'Side Plank', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"body"}, 
        {"id":7,"name":'Squat', "watchedToday": 'false', "type":"memory"}


        ]
    }
    ];
```

And on my template I iterate over it like following:

```
  <ion-list>

    <div *ngFor="let day of days"><br>
      <div (click)="toggleGroup(day)" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(day)}">
       <ion-icon *ngIf="!isGroupShown(day)" name="add"></ion-icon>
       <ion-icon *ngIf="isGroupShown(day)" name="remove"></ion-icon>
       {{day.name}}

     </div>

     <button ion-item [hidden]="!isGroupShown(day)" *ngFor="let exercise of day.exercises">
      {{exercise.name}}

      <!-- LED -->

      <span style="float:right;"><ion-icon *ngIf="exercise.watchedToday" name="checkmark"></ion-icon></span>      
    </button>

  </div>
</ion-list>
```

However this shows checkmarks for all the elements.

[image]

I want to show checkmark only for the list elements for which `watchedToday` is true like for first element in exercises. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON `watchedToday` is a string but it should be a boolean (you should remove the quotations)

```
this.days= [

    { "id": 0,
    "name": 'Ihr heutiger Trainingsplan',
    "exercises":[

    {"id":1,"name":'Best Stretch', "watchedToday": true, "type":"body"},
    {"id":8,"name":'Farben', "watchedToday": false, "type":"memory"},

    ...

    ]
}
];
```